how to trigger the http trigger in function using a button flutter?
I am currently trying a http trigger in azure functions. But the trigger should happen if I click a button on my flutter web application. Should I use REST API or any other way to do this.
the url is

https://functionappname.azurewebsites.net/api/http_trigger?blob_name=file.text

Code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Azure Function Trigger',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<void> triggerAzureFunction() async {
    // Replace 'YOUR_FUNCTION_URL' with the URL of your Azure Function HTTP trigger
    final url = Uri.parse('YOUR_FUNCTION_URL');

    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('Azure Function triggered successfully');
        // Handle success response
      } else {
        print('Failed to trigger Azure Function: ${response.statusCode}');
        // Handle failure response
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to trigger Azure Function: $e');
      // Handle exception
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Azure Function Trigger'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: triggerAzureFunction,
          child: Text('Trigger Azure Function'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

error

Failed to trigger Azure Function: XMLHttpRequest error.

I suspected CORS so given the "*" to allow all request.
Still getting the same error


Validate your function URL.

To trigger the Http trigger function, you have to pass the function URL in the code.

Failed to trigger Azure Function: XMLHttpRequest error.

It is a CORS error, to resolve this error, implement a backend layer that calls the function URL.

Configure CORS setting under API in your Azure Function App to allow the access to Web app or *.
If you have header attribute from the post method, delete it and configure CORS in Portal.


Code Snippet:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Azure Function Data Fetcher',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? data;

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    String url = "https://functionname.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger";
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          data = response.body;
        });
      } else {
        print('Failed to fetch data. Error code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error fetching data: $error');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Azure Function Data Fetcher'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: fetchData,
              child: Text('Fetch Data from Azure Function'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (data != null)
              Text(
                'Data from Azure Function: $data',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


References:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-flutter-http

Thank you, the CORS config worked deleted existing and added *.
Previously I kept both existing and * in CORS
